# Error archivo config mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, nodejs

Estoy tratando de conectarme a mi base de datos local y estos son los parametros que tengo:

```
 var config = {
    user: 'Eduard-PC\EdwarD',
    password: '',
    server: 'EDUARD-PC\SQLEXPRESS',
    database: 'nodejslogin'
};
```

Me saca el siguiente error:

> E:\Paginas\connn>node server.js
>   Server is running..
>   { Error: Failed to connect to EDUARD-PCSQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND E
>   DUARD-PCSQLEXPRESS
>       at Connection.tedious.once.err (E:\Paginas\connn\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedi
>   ous.js:216:17)
>       at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at Connection.socketError (E:\Paginas\connn\node_modules\tedious\lib\connect
>   ion.js:699:14)
>       at E:\Paginas\connn\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:590:25
>       at E:\Paginas\connn\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:68:18
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:89:17)
>     code: 'ESOCKET',
>     originalError:
>      { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to EDUARD-PCSQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinf
>   o ENOTFOUND EDUARD-PCSQLEXPRESS
>          at ConnectionError (E:\Paginas\connn\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:1
>   2:12)
>          at Connection.socketError (E:\Paginas\connn\node_modules\tedious\lib\conn
>   ection.js:699:30)
>          at E:\Paginas\connn\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:590:25
>          at E:\Paginas\connn\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:68:18
>          at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
>          at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:89:17)
>        message: 'Failed to connect to EDUARD-PCSQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTF
>   OUND EDUARD-PCSQLEXPRESS',
>        code: 'ESOCKET' },
>     name: 'ConnectionError' }
>   { ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
>       at Request._query (E:\Paginas\connn\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1300:37)
>       at Request._query (E:\Paginas\connn\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:497:11
>   )
>       at Request.query (E:\Paginas\connn\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1243:12)
>       at E:\Paginas\connn\server.js:25:17
>       at _poolCreate.then.catch.err (E:\Paginas\connn\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.
>   js:270:7) code: 'ECONNCLOSED', name: 'ConnectionError' }

Yo creo que es porque me queda de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no me reconoce el `\`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

en server coloca la ip, si la tienes en tu maquina coloca 127.0.0.1